# ParticleEffect using TextureAtlas in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, assets, particles, asset-management

I am using `ParticleEffect` with a texture stored inside `TextureAtlas`. The code below shows how I load a particle:

```
ParticleEffect particle = new ParticleEffect();
particle.load(Gdx.files.internal("particles/particle01.pe"), gamePlayAtlas);
```

I am not sure if I have to call `particle.dispose()` inside `ApplicationLister`'s `dispose` method, or is it enough if I only call `dispose` on the `AssetManager` instance with which I loaded the `TextureAtlas`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `ParticleEffect` owns the texture you need to call `dispose`, and it owns it only if the texture is loaded using a `FileHandle`, so if it comes from `TextureAtlas` it doesn't own it and you don't need to call `dispose`.

But, the `dispose` method of `ParticleEffect` is aware of this so it's safe to call `dispose` even if it is not the owner of the texture.

[ParticleEffect source code for the `dispose` method](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/ParticleEffect.java#L247)